# gzip compression for API call in Swift

Tags: json, swift, compression, gzip, deflate

I'm working in Swift with an API that requires you to send JSON compressed using gzip or deflate in the body of your HTTP request. How would I convert testEventModel below into the required compressed JSON format?

```
struct EventModel: Codable {
    var eventType: String
    var eventName: String?
}

var testEventModel = EventModel(eventType: "TestEvent", eventName: "TestName")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way, would be to use an existing library for gzipping content, like this one: https://github.com/1024jp/GzipSwift . then your code could look like follows:

```
guard let jsonData = try? JSONEncoder().encode(testEventModel),
      let url = URL(string: "https://api.com/endpoint") else {
    return
}
let gzipped = jsonData.gzipped()

var request = URLRequest(url: url)
let postLength = String(format: "%lu", UInt(gzipped.count))
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue(postLength, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
request.addValue("gzip", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Encoding")
request.httpBody = gzipped

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    // handle response
}.resume()
```